# Grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume in Centos 7

Tags: raid, centos7, grub, grub2, hetzner

After replacing the disk with raid 1, I have this problem:

```
grub2-install --recheck /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may
be missing from core image..
grub2-install: warning: Couldn't find physical volume `(null)'. Some modules may
be missing from core image..
Installation finished. No error reported.


# cat /proc/mdstat:

    Personalities : [raid1] 
    md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[2] nvme1n1p1[1]
          33521664 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
          
    md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[2] nvme1n1p3[1]
          465895744 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
          bitmap: 4/4 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk
    
    md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[2] nvme1n1p2[1]
          523712 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

OS Centos 7 with software Raid 1

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:7    0 444.4G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
nvme1n1     259:1    0   477G  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme1n1p2 259:3    0   512M  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0 511.4M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme1n1p3 259:4    0 444.4G  0 part  
  └─md2       9:2    0 444.3G  0 raid1 /
```

Is it UEFI - I do not know, a dedicated server PX61 at Hetzner

Comment: Please, show `lsblk`. Also, why you aren't using EFI?